Using python 3.12 generics and mypy
I want to achieve something like this:

from collections import deque
from typing import Iterable

import numpy as np


def mean[T](a: Iterable[T]) -> T:
    s = sum(a)
    return s * (1.0/len(a))


c = mean([1.0, 1.5])
print(c)

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = mean([a, b])
print(c)

print(mean((1,2,3)) )

d = deque([a,b])
print(mean(d))

but I want that code not only correctly work - which is achieved now, but also to be accepted by mypy. As for now I can't overcome errors like this:
mypy  mypy_explore.py
    mypy_explore.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "sum" has incompatible type "Iterable[T]"; expected "Iterable[bool]"  [arg-type]
    mypy_explore.py:9: error: Unsupported operand types for / ("float" and "int")  [operator]
    mypy_explore.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Iterable[T]"; expected "Sized"  [arg-type]
    mypy_explore.py:17: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]", variable has type "float")  [assignment]
    Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I have tested many methods, also using Protocol, but none of them successfully, I feel that this should be easy to achieve, just a sequence of any type supporting sum and multiplication by number should be accepted, but it is not...
I tried also this:
from collections import deque
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np


def mean[T](a: Sequence[T]) -> T:
    la = list(a)
    s = a[0]
    for i in la[1:]:
        s = s + i
    return s * (1.0/len(a))


c = mean([1.0, 1.5])
print(c)

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = mean([a, b])
print(c)

print(mean((1,2,3)) )

d = deque([a,b])
print(mean(d))

and errors where like this:
mypy_explore.py : 4 errors 
Unsupported left operand type for + ("T")  [operator] (11:12)
Unsupported operand types for * ("T" and "float")  [operator] (12:11)
Incompatible return value type (got "float", expected "T")  [return-value] (12:11)
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]", variable has type "float")  [assignment] (20:4)


For starters, Iterable won't work, because not all iterables support computing their length. The closest available type is collections.abc.Collection, which subclasses Sized and Iterable, but also requires __contains__. If you need to stick with Iterable, you'll need to use something less efficient to compute the length while computing the sum.

Type-wise, the default starting value of 0 used by sum isn't appropriate for any possible type bound to T. You've gotten lucky in your testing that 0 is sufficient at runtime. You may need to bound or constrain T to number-like types, but I don't know if there's an easy way to do that which incorporates NumPy arrays, matrices, etc.

You might want to see how sum is typed in the first place, starting here.

(Looking at sum, there is an overload that ignores the starting value, so that may not play into the weird inference of bool as I speculated it might.)

Indeed. Iterable is not good type hint,  for my needs Sequence would be more than enough. So I tried this, and changed sum function into manual loop, errors now are different

You still don't have any restrictions on T. Will your function work given [A(), A()], where A is just class A: pass? I think no, since you can't add A's together and can't multiply an A by a float. That's exactly what mypy says. You could use a typing.Protocol to define the minimal required methods and use it as an upper bound for T.

Like this (with numpy excluded as it's not available in playground, but should either work as-is or be easy to tweak). And no need to do list(a) for a Sequence - it already supports len(), item access, slicing and iteration.

@STerliakov - you are right when it comes to len(), but there is also la[1:] which is not applicable to all Sequences

@STerliakov - Thanks for the mypy solution , that Self was probably the  lacking element in my attempts!

Slicing with a slice is fine for Sequences too: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/773b493b2b088fdeb3347c2ec9b1aab2cb4b4e33/stdlib/typing.pyi#L609. Yoh don't need to convert to a list. And no need for a loop either, just sum(a[1:], a[0]) - you can pass a custom start parameter to sum.
